# String variable passed to function as Class object

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react native app, I have a dictionary of which I have stored the keys in an array using `this.setState({keys: Object.keys(dict)})`. I am trying to iterate over and render these keys which when clicked pass the key name to a function as so:

```
this.state.keys.map((key, index) => {
  return (
    <View key={index}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={key => this.doSomething(key)}>
        <View>
          <Text>{key}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

Each key is displayed  correctly in the Text component, but when clicked the onPress function receives a Class object rather than the string that is correctly rendered:

```
 Class {
    "_dispatchInstances": null,
    "_dispatchListeners": null,
    "_targetInst": FiberNode {
      "tag": 5,
      "key": null,
      "type": "RCTView",
    },
    "bubbles": undefined,
    "cancelable": undefined,
    "currentTarget": null,
    "defaultPrevented": undefined,
    "dispatchConfig": Object {
      "dependencies": Array [],
      "registrationName": "onResponderGrant",
    },
    "eventPhase": undefined,
    "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    "isPersistent": [Function functionThatReturnsTrue],
    "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    "isTrusted": undefined,
    "nativeEvent": Object {
      "changedTouches": Array [
        [Circular],
      ],
      "identifier": 0,
      "locationX": 4.013671875,
      "locationY": 11.8740234375,
      "pageX": 169.013671875,
      "pageY": 275.8740234375,
      "target": 207,
      "timestamp": 30722773,
      "touches": Array [
        [Circular],
      ],
    },
    "target": 207,
    "timeStamp": 1586871822926,
    "touchHistory": Object {
      "indexOfSingleActiveTouch": 0,
      "mostRecentTimeStamp": 30722855,
      "numberActiveTouches": 0,
      "touchBank": Array [
        Object {
          "currentPageX": 169.1015625,
          "currentPageY": 277.138671875,
          "currentTimeStamp": 30722855,
          "previousPageX": 169.1015625,
          "previousPageY": 277.138671875,
          "previousTimeStamp": 30722853,
          "startPageX": 169.013671875,
          "startPageY": 275.8740234375,
          "startTimeStamp": 30722773,
          "touchActive": false,
        },
      ],
    },
    "type": undefined,
  },
```

Why does the String get passed to the onPress function as a Class object?

Comment: this key onPress is a synthetic event, you should rename it for evt ou pass a empty parenthesis then do the rest normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is passing the Event as the first parameter to your function. When you write `{key =>`, you are creating a new variable called `key` that is actually the Event, not the expected string. You could just put empty parentheses (or name the param anything other than `key`) and it should work as you expect. For example:

```html
onPress={() => this.doSomething(key)}`
```